# Populate list box from string on different lines

Tags: vb.net

I have a query that returns a list of items that are in one listbox but not another. I want to put the results of that into a different listbox, problem is that when I try to put the results into a listbox, it puts them all on the same line. Say it returns three results (project_green Project_blue_ project_red), its adding them to one line in the list box as (project_greenproject_blueproject_red). I want each item to be on its own line but I can't get it there.

Here is the code I have

```
Dim result As List(Of String) = (From s1 As String In Me.ListBox1.Items Where Not Me.ListBox4.Items.Contains(s1) Select s1).ToList()
ListBox5.Items.Add(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61964996/10216583) again: `ListBox5.Items.AddRange(ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).Except(ListBox4.Items.Cast(Of String)).ToArray)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim result = From s1 As String In ListBox1.Items Where Not ListBox4.Items.Contains(s1) Select s1
ListBox5.Items.AddRange(result)
```

This also saves you a bunch of extra memory. There's no need to allocate a `List` when the `IEnumerable` result form the linq query will already do on its own.

Though personally, I'm not a fan of the query comprehension syntax and prefer to write it this way:

```
Dim result = ListBox1.Items.Where(Function(s1) Not ListBox4.Items.Contains(s1))
ListBox5.Items.AddRange(result)
```

Comment: I've tried to just put result but I get this error
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'AddRange' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Overloads Sub AddRange(value As ListBox.ObjectCollection)': Argument matching parameter 'value' narrows from 'IEnumerable(Of String)' to 'ListBox.ObjectCollection'.
    'Public Overloads Sub AddRange(items As Object())': Argument matching parameter 'items' narrows from 'IEnumerable(Of String)' to 'Object()'


If I use your shorter code, I get this error
 'Where' is not a member of 'ListBox.ObjectCollection'

Comment: With Option Strict on I get an error on `As String` in the first listing. Items are Objects, I believe.

Comment: In the second lising `.Where` is not a member of ListBox.ObjectCollection (no extension methods).

Comment: Just remove the `As String` and `.AddRange(result)` to `.AddRange(result.ToArray)` in the first listing.

Comment: Damn, I tried toarray in different spots but not there I guess. Thanks!